# Generating RESTful Webservices from entity classes in a netbeans maven webapp causes app to fail, displaying "Payara Server, deploy, null, false"

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, microservices, payara

I want to make a persistence microservice for my application with jee 8.The resource endpoint works well with a simple **PersistenceResource** class. I have generated the **entities** from the **mysql** database and the app still works fine. Unfortunately, the moment i generate **'RESTful WebServices from entity classes'** payara server fails to run. The message in the server log is

`Deploying on Payara Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at /home/nkengasong/NetBeansProjects/CreatixxPersistence/target/CreatixxPersistence
Payara Server, deploy, null, false`

The same error is displayed when i generate **Session Beans For Entity Classes**. **Please what might be the problem?** I have been searching the internet for hours now.

The app is a traditional **maven-archetype-webapp** and i am using:

NetBeans IDE 9.0

Payara Server

Java EE 8

Open JDK 11

Ubuntu 18.04 lts (same problem on windows 10)

Below is my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.jee8ng</groupId>
<artifactId>CreatixxPersistence</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>CreatixxPersistence Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>  

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.16</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>CreatixxPersistence</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This is the structure of the app:

[Here is the structure of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuRvd.png)

I seriously need help! Please why is that the app stops running when i generate the webservices or sessions? How can i remedy this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Yes @Rafael, this is it                                                                                    
 `Deploying on Payara Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at /home/nkengasong/NetBeansProjects/CreatixxPersistence/target/CreatixxPersistence
Payara Server, deploy, null, false`

Comment: @Rafael that is the only stack trace in the payara server log

Comment: Are you deploying from netbeans? Is this output in netbeans itself?- check the server.log *file*, that there's no deployment exception being thrown.

Comment: @MarkW yes i am deploying in netbeans. No exception is thrown just `Payara Server, deploy, null, false`

Comment: The message "Payara Server, deploy, null, false" is just a message from Netbeans and it means that Netbeans wasn't able to deploy the app. The real reason can be found in Payara Server logs - open the server log of Payara Server from Netbeans to see the error (In Services View, expand servers, then right-click on Payara Server and choose View server log). Please copy all the errors you see into the question.

Comment: @OndrejM here is the error `Unexpected Exception Priority: SILENT Category: Error                                                                                     Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.logging.resources.logging, locale en_US`

Answer (score 2):

Payara server is not yet fully compatible with JDK 11. You still need a JDK 8 version.

Comment: Rudy is right, you need JDK 8 to run Payara Server 5. Support for JDK 11 is planned for the next year (2019).

Comment: @OndrejM i downgraded my jdk to jdk 1.8 but to no avail. I still get the SAME error, i have tried everything over the internet but nothing works

Comment: @CaptainA Can you just generate the WAR file with Maven (mvn clean package for example) and deploy it to Payara Server outside of NetBeans. Then you should be able to see the real exception within the server log files.
What version of Payara Server and JDK 8 are you using?

Comment: @RudyDeBusscher i am using Payara Server 5.183 #badassfish (build 380) && oracle jdk i think 1.8.0_162 as per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04. The error is: `Unexpected Exception Priority: SILENT Category: Error Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.logging.resources.logging, locale en_US`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by switching to NetBeans 8.2 and changing the default @XmlTransient annotation on certain fields of the entity classes to @JsonbTransient
(this avoids stackoverflow error, if you intend to use JSON instead of XML). By default, when you generate entity classes from the database, certain fields get annotated with @XmlTransient. I switched netbeans because apparently NetBeans IDE 9.0 is not stable. I hope this helps someone. Thanks to everyone for you help!